# Importance of SQLite in iPhone Application Development

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am in iPhone Application Development since last few months only..

So, I have working with some applications, and in all of the applications i used to follow the SOAP web service methods to get the data in my applications.

I have heard something on SQLite, but have lots of confusion regarding important of it.

So, if anybody can explain or just give me a hint regarding on SQLite will highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite is a database if you want to have data stored you can use it. You use web service because the data is not stored locally. SQLite allows you to store data locally. 
http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/ 
http://www.mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/

Comment: @zapping - Thanks a lot for your feedback... But what should be the limitations for the storing data locally in iPhone Device ? Means in which situation we should store data locally ?

Comment: If you would like to persist some information in your application, or if you want to allow users to work offline and then sync the data to your server, etc. The limit will depend on the phone capacity.

Comment: this is on limit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752830/how-much-can-sqlite-store-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell SQLite is a library used to provide local database access to your iPhone app.

http://www.sqlite.org/