# iphone memory issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, memory, uiimage

I have an iPhone application that will save number of images in it.
I used SQLite in-order to save the images into the application.
There were lot of memory issues after i saved more than 20 images.

Do any one know how many images users can save in their app database?.
if it depends on iphone memory, how can we get that max limit?.

One more thing:

I have removed the database and used the file system to store the images into application.
but same problem replicated.

Can any one suggest me on this.
I owe a lot for your great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say 'memory issue', do you mean leaks causing out of memory exceptions or are you sure your database has filled the device's disk completely. To know how much SQLite can store read the discussion on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752830/how-much-can-sqlite-store-on-the-iphone).

On the other hand, if you are having out of memory exceptions (didReceiveMemoryWarning) you need to tune your code. Specially, when working with many images, just avoiding the use of '`imageNamed`' factory method does the job. This is because it creates an autorelease object which remains longer in the memory. Instead create UIImages using the '`initWithContentsOfFile`' to create the image and release it immediately after it is used. If you still face the memory issue, you probably have some leaks and need to post some code for people to answer more correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I believe storing the image in the file system is a much better idea, could you provide us with more information, like image size, and also some of your saving code?