# Huge Offline Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have to develop an app which having 200MB sqlite database in zipped form. my app will support 2.2 and above and below is my requirement.

1. Offline is an option and is initiated after the app is downloaded from app store
2. Offline database can be deleted from the device, independently of uninstalling the app
3. User can choose where they want to save database (SD card or phone memory)

what is your thoughts ???

Suggestions are welcome.. :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: on iPhone, you have a 50MB max for sqlite (see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752830/how-much-can-sqlite-store-on-the-iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752830/how-much-can-sqlite-store-on-the-iphone)).

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: i need to implement it in android and as you know that apk size is max 50 MB so how i can use 200 MB sqlite db in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to look at using an [expansion APK](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html). These can be up to 2GB in size.